# Gazebo is not installed on Ubuntu

Tags: gazebo

I am trying to install Gazebo, but there is not release version for Mantic in the package.

```
E: The repository 'http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: What ros distribution and operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur) is not officially supported by Gazebo, see [here](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/getstarted). If you can, switch to Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy as this will be a simple, beginner friendly installation.

Otherwise you can try the [source installation](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/install_ubuntu_src) where you compile your own Gazebo version from the source code. But there might be some pitfalls and simply copying the commands from the documentation for Ubuntu 22.04 will probably not work.